# Putting pre-defined text into a HTML form text box

Tags: html, css, forms, input

Using HTML/CSS is it possible to do the following?

In a form asking for the user's website, I want to have the `http://www.` or just `www.` put into the text box so the user doesn't have to. I know it's only something small, but is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you use a normal single-line text input box, `<input type=text>`, you can use the `value` attribute to specify an initial (default) value, e.g.

```
<input type=text name=site value="http://www.">
```

However, this is questionable for several reasons. First, the value provided is not really a meaningful default value, just a fragment. Second, it is actually a nuisance if the user needs to enter a URL that has a different protocol part, like https:, or the first part of the server name is not www, or, most importantly perhaps, if he intends to cut and paste an address, as he really should (to guarantee against typing errors).

The same applies even stronger to `<input type=url>`, which is the HTML5 approach for input like this. Using it, `value="http://www."` would set the field to invalid state.

Thus, you get better usability by *not* setting any initial value in the field.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what kind of textbox you are using.

If you are using a textarea, you can use @Wavemaster's solution:

```
<textarea>www.</textarea>
```

If you're using a textbox, you can use the `value` attribute:

```
<input type="text" value="www." />
```

Hope this helped, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a `<textarea>`, you can just add your text between the start and the end tag:

```
<textarea>www.</textarea>
```

for `<input>` just use the `value=""` property:

```
<input type="text" value="www."  />
```